# Java- Eclipse - Container path cannot be null

Tags: java, eclipse, error-handling

Had to reinstall eclipse the other day, and moved it from one folder to another.. not sure if its relevant but I am getting an error when trying to run one of my projects - this is a new project I have never run successfully before. I have also tried copying the code to a newly built project but still no luck.

An internal error occurred during: "Launching Main (14)".
**Container path cannot be null**

Other projects are running fine.

Not sure if this is relevant but pom.xml below:

```
       <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>GmailTest2</groupId>
  <artifactId>GmailTest2</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>GmailTest2</name>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client-http</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3-alpha</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>enter code here
```

Comment: Are you move entire folder right?

Comment: which folder? eclipse?